# Should [web-worker] be used for Node.js workers?

Tags: discussion, tags

Web workers are new browser feature that allows a new thread to start and communicate with it using messages. Soon after being implemented, Node.js ports popped out that are internally using child process API.

I'm not really sure if questions about Node.js ports should use the web-worker tag because they work differently (internally) and most of the time, if not always, are used to solve completely different problems.

I followed [web-worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-worker) for few months and I never had anything to say about the [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) questions (though I do use Node.js myself occasionally). I think something like [node-workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-workers) should exist instead. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag wiki for [web-worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-worker) specifically calls out the specification of the **browser-based** Web Worker.

[Node.js' Worker class](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/cluster.html#cluster_class_worker) is part of its Cluster API.

The APIs are very different.

This difference leads me to agree with the OP that we need a new tag.

Comment: OP isn't talking about the Cluster API, but about Node.js Web Workers ports. And there already is a [node-cluster] tag.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, as long as these Node.js Web Workers ports have the same API as browser Web Workers, questions about them should be tagged with [web-worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-worker). It's irrelevant what they are using internally.

Comment: Like McCaughan said they do not have the same API.